# Wifi connected to AP but no internet access

Tags: networking, wifi

Broadcom BR4321 was working with `b43` except for being slow and intermittent therefore I switched to `wl` instead. Configuration updated basically be replacing `wlan0` with `wls1` but can't connect to internet.

```
# lspci -knn
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4328] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:0087]
        Kernel driver in use: wl
        Kernel modules: ssb, wl

# ip a
3: wls1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:17:f2:99:7b:9b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.43.195/24 brd 192.168.43.255 scope global dynamic wls1
       valid_lft 3388sec preferred_lft 3388sec
    inet6 fe80::217:f2ff:fe99:7b9b/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

# iptables-save
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Wed Oct 14 09:34:50 2020
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [2560:230581]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [75:39057]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1941:305885]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Oct 14 09:34:50 2020
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Wed Oct 14 09:34:50 2020
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [70:7158]
:INPUT ACCEPT [46:3604]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [11:1383]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [30:2604]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Oct 14 09:34:50 2020
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Wed Oct 14 09:34:50 2020
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [2701:276272]
:INPUT ACCEPT [2560:230581]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [88:40760]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1941:305885]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2158:366414]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Oct 14 09:34:50 2020

# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp2s0 inet manual

iface enx00808e8a9039 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        bridge_ports enp2s0 enx00808e8a9039
        address 192.168.1.51
        netmask 255.255.255.0

auto wls1
allow-hotplug wls1
iface wls1 inet dhcp
        wpa-ssid RWB
        wpa-psk password

# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 192.168.43.34
```

On reboot the machine connects to my access point, but it can't use the Internet:

```
# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
47 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 146ms

# ip route
default via 192.168.43.34 dev wls1
192.168.1.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.51
192.168.43.0/24 dev wls1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.195
```

**Update: ping to gateway and ip neighbours**

I can't ping the gateway (192.168.43.34), but I can if I switch to a different wifi adapter that does work then I can.

Working adapter:

```
# ip nei show
192.168.1.19 dev br0 lladdr 04:0e:3c:a0:25:72 REACHABLE
192.168.43.34 dev wlx00e032800384 lladdr 94:65:2d:71:3b:91 DELAY
192.168.1.10 dev br0 lladdr b0:48:7a:80:7e:69 REACHABLE
```

The troublesome adapter:

```
# ip nei show
192.168.1.19 dev br0 lladdr 04:0e:3c:a0:25:72 STALE
192.168.43.34 dev wls1 lladdr 94:65:2d:71:3b:91 REACHABLE
192.168.1.10 dev br0 lladdr b0:48:7a:80:7e:69 REACHABLE
```

(.10 is my win10 desktop, .19 is my work laptop.)

**Update: speed tests**

Three different adapters. Respectively: a PCI card on a different machine, built-in, USB. All going through the same access point.

The BC4321 slowed to a crawl -- like dial-up -- which is what prompted me to try the `wl` driver instead of the `bc43` driver.

[image]

Comment: Can you ping the router? E.g. `ping 192.168.43.34` ?

Comment: also any result from `ip nei show` with wls1 ?

Comment: I can't.
But I can if I use the other wifi interface (Realtek 8811cu) that does work then I can.
I think you're on to something...

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the wifi re-connection problem by changing the configuration to *roaming* defining a `network` in `wpa_supplicant.conf` and then referencing it in `/etc/network/interfaces` like this:

```
### WiFi to Internet: physical plus virtual for each network defined in wpa_supplicant.conf

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
        wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
#        wpa-ssid RWB
#        wpa-psk password

allow-hotplug RWB
iface RWB inet dhcp
```

On the speed: switching the main AP From 2.4GHz to 5GHz made one big difference, and using a WiFi scanner app and a lot of walking around the house monitoring signal strength to find a good channel for the 2.4GHz internal network.